# Clear Command Deleting One Less Message(Java Discord JDA)

Tags: java, discord-jda

I'm trying to make it so whenever someone does !clear [Amount] it will delete the amount of messages in the [Amount]. The problem I'm having is that the !clear [Amount] deletes 1 less message. For example, if someone does !clear 3, it will delete the "!clear 3" and 2 messages above it. I want to make it so that whenever someone does !clear 3, it will delete the "!clear 3" and delete the 3 messages above it. Can someone help me edit my code please?

Here's my code:

```
package Events;

import net.dv8tion.jda.api.EmbedBuilder;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.Message;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.events.message.guild.GuildMessageReceivedEvent;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.ListenerAdapter;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Clear  extends ListenerAdapter {
    public void onGuildMessageReceived(GuildMessageReceivedEvent e) {
        String[] args = e.getMessage().getContentRaw().split("\\s+");

        if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("!clear")) {
            if (args.length < 2) {
                EmbedBuilder usage = new EmbedBuilder();
                usage.setColor(0xff3923);
                usage.setTitle("Specify amount to delete");
                usage.setDescription("Usage: !clear [# of messages]");
                e.getChannel().sendMessage(usage.build()).queue();
            } else {
                List<Message> messages = e.getChannel().getHistory().retrievePast(Integer.parseInt(args[1])).complete();
                e.getChannel().deleteMessages(messages).queue();
                e.getChannel().sendMessage("Messages has been deleted!").queue(m -> m.delete().queueAfter(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just use `.retrievePast(Integer.parseInt(args[1])+1)` so you get one message more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit from:

```
.retrievePast(Integer.parseInt(args[1]))
```

to:

```
.retrievePast(Integer.parseInt(args[1])+1)
```

All credit goes to [dan1st](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10871900/dan1st)(tysm <3)